# No email received when sending email from gmail using PHP Mailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Below is the PHP Mailer code I use to send email from gmail to another mail server.

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->isSMTP();                                        
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 
$mail->Username = 'distechktn@gmail.com';      
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';                        
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                              
$mail->Port = 587;                                      

$mail->From = 'distechktn@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Server';
$mail->addAddress('amalina@distech.com.my');

$body  = "Test from Server <br>";
$body  = "Thank you";

$mail->Subject = 'Test';
$mail->Body = $body;                                    
$mail->isHTML(true); 

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

After processing the process, this is the notification that I've got. It says that the **message has been sent**. But when I checked my email, there's no email received in the inbox. Is there something wrong with my mail server? And when I tried sending it to a different gmail account, it works. Please help me.

```
2016-03-17 09:06:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 192.168.1.20
2016-03-17 09:06:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-03-17 09:06:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 192.168.1.20
2016-03-17 09:06:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2016-03-17 09:06:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: ZGlzdGVjaGt0bkBnbWFpbC5jb20=
2016-03-17 09:06:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: ZGlzdGVjaDE1MTM=
2016-03-17 09:06:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:
2016-03-17 09:06:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:
2016-03-17 09:06:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 10:06:23 +0100
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: amalina@distech.com.my
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Server
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Test
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID:
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.10 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: Thank you
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-03-17 09:06:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2016-03-17 09:06:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT Message has been sent
```

Comment: have your mail sent in spam ?

Comment: @AmitChauhan I've checked but there's none.

Comment: @amln_ndh you need to configure `IMAP setting` enable in your gmail account.

Comment: @Yash do I need to enable my IMAP?

Comment: @amln_ndh for more check this [link](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?authuser=1&authuser=1&hl=en&authuser=1&rd=2)

Comment: Just in case, make sure you generate a valid return path to receive bounces. (No idea whether PhpMailer does it automatically from `$mail->From`.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with IMAP. You're trying to send mail via SMTP. IMAP is for fetching mail.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the MAIL FROM:, and no address in the From: header either. So this e-mail will look very suspect to any receiving server. Ie, when Gmail tries to forward it to the distech.com.my domain, that domain's mail server is very likely to reject it. And because there's no sender address, there's nowhere to send a bounce to.

So, in summary, fix the from address and try again.

Comment: By the way, the server code transcript gives away your gmail username and password, which are base64-encoded. ZGlzdGVjaDE1MTM decodes to... well, it is easy to decode anyway. I recommend changing that password now.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your gmail account settings and right at the bottom, turn on the allow less secure apps option and then wait for about 15 minutes before running your script again and then it should work!